# c# invoking JDE XMLcallobject compatibilty with Visual Studio 2010 and XMLinterop.dll

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, jdedwards

JDE xmlinterop.dll giving error code 14 when trying to do a pinvoke from C# in Visual studio 2010 environment - can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Error code 14 is "The connection to JD Edwards EnterpriseOne failed". Check enterprise server name, port and environment name.